# spring cloud stream kafka - Functional approach: Consumer is never called when producing tombstone records

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, tombstone, spring-cloud-function

The issue is pretty much the same as https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/455 but for the **`Functional`** approach

```
    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<Foo>> fooConsumer() {
        return message -> {
            String key = // From message header - KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY
            Foo payLoad = message.getPayload();

            if (payLoad == null) {
                deleteSomething(key);
            } else {
                addSomething(key, payLoad);
            }
        };
    }
```

When a proper 'Foo' (json) is produced the fooConsumer is invoked. But when a 'null' payload/tombstone is produced the consumer function is never called.

Workaround I tried with Custom **'Convertor'** approach which is working:

```
@Component
public class KafkaNullConverter extends MappingJackson2MessageConverter {

    @Override
    protected Object convertFromInternal(Message<?> message, @NonNull Class<?> targetClass, Object conversionHint) {
        if (message.getPayload() instanceof KafkaNull) {
            return Foo.builder().isDeleted(true).build(); // Note: new `isDeleted` field added to `Foo`
        }

        return super.convertFromInternal(message, targetClass, conversionHint);
    }
}
```

The `fooConsumer` then can check `payload.isDeleted()` to handle `null` case.
But this is verbose, pollutes pojo/model classes and have to repeat for every consumers.

I understand that spring-integration cannot working with null. But are there any better/standard approach to handle the 'tombstone' use-case with Functional approach?

Version: **3.0.4.RELEASE**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was recently fixed on the main branch https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/pull/936 and https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/557

Comment: I should probably open a new question for this, but in the current impl of spring-cloud-function, this seems to get worse: see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/main/spring-cloud-function-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/function/context/catalog/SimpleFunctionRegistry.java#L1025
How are we supposed to handle a KafkaNull, when we don't get the key that TombStone record belongs to?

Comment: Yes, you should. The key is provided in a message header; `KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_KEY` (`RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY` in older versions).

Comment: Thanks, Gary, that's what we used to do, but doesn't work anymore since our latest update. Our fix, found in some github-issue: use a BiConsumer<Event, Map<String, String>>, instead of a Consumer<Message>.